# Non-deterministic TM and problems in class P

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, polynomial-time, nondeterminism

Definition:
$\text{P}$ is the set of languages that can be decided by a deterministic Turing Machine in polynomial time.

I wonder if $\text{P}$ equals to the set of languages that can be decided by a non-deterministic Turing Machine in polynomial time?

I think this has to be true because a non-deterministic Turing Machine can also decide all problems which can be decided by a deterministic Turing Machine. Because of the fact that we have here a language in P this NTM also decides it in P.

Am I right or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if $\text{P}$ is the set of languages that can be decided by
> a non-deterministic Turing machine in polynomial time?

This is the same as asking whether $ \text{P} = \text{NP}$, where $\text{NP}$ is the set of languages that can be decided by nondeterminsitic Turing machines in polynomial time.  The question of whether $\text{P} =\text{NP}$ is an open problem. So we don't know the answer yet.

> I think this has to be true because a non-deterministic Turing Machine
> can also decide all problems which can be decided by a deterministic
> Turing Machine.

The fact that nondeterministic Turing machines can simulate deterministic Turing machines without any time blowup (simply by not using nondeterminisim) is straight-forward and only shows that $\text{P} \subseteq \text{NP}$, the mysterious open containment is the other one: we don't know yet whether deterministic Turing machines can simulate nondeterministic Turing machines with at most polynomial blow-up.

Comment: You have messed everything: P vs. NP asks if every problem in NP can be decided by deterministic Turing machine in polynomial time. His question is not that.

Comment: His question is that. Perhaps it wasn't written clearly enough by the asker.

Comment: I think the question is whether the notion that "a non-deterministic Turing Machine can also decide all problems which can be decided by a deterministic Turing Machine" is saying P=NP is correct. It is not correct, answered in passing with "This shows that P⊆NP". Perhaps, you can elaborate this a bit.

Comment: @rus9384 most answers interpret it as P vs NP, and my previous comment pinpoints OP's source of confusion.

Comment: It is indeed was not written clearly, but I think it asks whether P=NP: 
"I wonder if P is the set of languages that can be decided by a non-deterministic Turing machine in polynomial time?"

Comment: I agree that it asks whether P vs NP, but my previous comment explains the difference (if slight) to other P vs NP questions. The difference matters, because otherwise there is no question, since P vs NP is famously unsolved, and I can't imagine OP being unaware of it, looking at their previous questions. When I said "It is not correct", it is as an answer to OP's question, instead of asserting that you are not correct. Hence, I continue to ask for an explanation of the reason "This shows that P⊆NP", even if trivial.

Comment: @KennethKho $\text{P}\subseteq \text{NP}$ follows from the fact that an NTM can simply simulate a DTM without blowup in the runtime. If $M$ is a DTM that decides a language $L$ in polynomial time, then you can look at it as a NTM that does use nondeterminism at all, and so $L$ is also in $\text{NP}$, and this is what he has alluded to "a non-deterministic Turing Machine can also decide all problems which can be decided by a deterministic Turing Machine". I made a slight edit to the answer make it clearer.

Comment: Excellent, the edited answer has clearly explained why we can conclude P⊆NP and not also conclude NP⊆P from the quote.

Answer (score 1):

The class $P$ is a subset of $NP$. For an $NP$ algorithm to simulate $P$ in polynomial time, it does not even need to use nondeterminism, since a single branch can solve the $P$ problem.

It could be a bit confusing though when textbooks say that an $NP$ algorithm works in 'polynomial time'. But this refers to the amount of time it takes for a single branch to compute. But taken as a whole, $NP= \cup NTIME(n^k)$, while $P= \cup DTIME(n^k)$.

Answer (score 0):

Every problem of class `P` is also of class `NP`. `NP` means we can verify a solution to a problem in polynomial time. If a problem is in the `P` class, one method of verifying the solution would be to find the solution in polynomial time. Thus, the `P` problem is `NP` class.